# Я правильно понимаю, что пунктуация неверна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, дополнение

Снова фраза из учебника:

> В России наряду с названными выше звеньями образовательной системы, существует ряд путей непрерывного образования.

Я же правильно понимаю, что оборот *наряду с* должен быть либо обособлен, либо нет?

1. > В России, наряду с названными выше звеньями образовательной системы, существует ряд путей непрерывного образования;
2. > В России наряду с названными выше звеньями образовательной системы существует ряд путей непрерывного образования.

То есть либо 1, либо 2.

Но здесь использовался «полуобособленный» вариант. Но так не должно быть, верно?

Comment: по идее должен быть обособлен. В России на(ряду) с - перебор с предлогами-союзами явно.

Comment: Д.Розенталь описывает такие конструкции и предоставляет право выбора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• В [учебнике](http://vip8082p.vip8081p.beget.tech/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_8_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2/13.2.html) обществознания (Л. Н. Боголюбов, Н. И. Городецкая, Л. Ф. Иванова и др.) это предложение написано **без** запятых:
*В России наряду с названными выше звеньями образовательной системы существует ряд путей непрерывного образования.*

• Вы правы, «полуобособленного» варианта быть не должно.

> Обороты со значением **включения, исключения и замещения**... выделяются или не выделяются запятыми по условиям контекста. Такие обороты включают предлоги и предложные сочетания ***кроме, наряду с, помимо, (не) исключая, за исключением, включая, сверх, вместо*** и др.
>
> Обособление **обязательно** при следующих условиях: расположение в абсолютном начале предложения; расположение между подлежащим и сказуемым (разрыв их связи); расположение между управляющим словом и управляемым (разрыв их снязи): *Когда наступили трудные годы Гражданской войны, Лизе, **наряду со всеми,** пришлось искать службу* (Фед.)...

• Примеры:

*В уголовных законах некоторых стран... помещены статьи, предусматривающие ответственность **наряду с названными выше деяниями** также за торговлю людьми и (или) вербовку людей для сексуальной или иной эксплуатации путем обмана...* (Коллектив авторов. Захват заложника);

*Вот почему **наряду с названными тремя властями** необходим в качестве особого, самостоятельного института глава государства (президент — в республике; монарх — в конституционной монархии)* (С. С. Алексеев. Государство и право).

[Знаки препинания при ограничительно-выделительных оборотах](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=387) (ПАС)

Comment: У меня именно так там написано. С одной стороны есть запятая, с другой нет.

Answer (score 2):

*В России(?) / **наряду с названными выше звеньями образовательной системы,** // существует ряд путей непрерывного образования.*

1. Итак, первой запятой **нет**, а по правилам ее нужно поставить.

Но ситуация интересна тем, что первая пауза **произносительная,** а она обычно **не обозначается** запятой. Здесь нет интерпозиции и вставочной интонации, то есть нет выделения оборота двумя **одинаковыми** паузами.

2. Нужно ли считать такую запись **ошибкой** или это продуманное решение?  Трудно сказать, но допустим, что **не ошибка.** Как мне думается, здесь возможно такое **понимание**.

На **первом** месте (в составе обособленного обстоятельственного **оборота**) обстоятельство места ***"В России"***, а на **втором** — оборот с предлогом ***НАРЯДУ С***.  Отношения обозначены как **неоднородные**.

Всю конструкцию можно рассматривать как обособленный обстоятельственный **детерминант** по отношению к **основному** содержанию предложения.

3. С другой стороны, в правилах такая ситуация **не обозначена.** Но, может быть, **практика** письма  пока еще не отражена в правилах.

Comment: Может, 1-й пункт надо изменить? А то получается, что запятой нет, а "первая запятая грамматическая". (Есть произносительная пауза, не обозначенная запятой...)

Comment: Спасибо, я  изменила первый пункт.